# ASP.Net Core: Database connection fails when the password is changed, but works when the application is restarted

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have an ASP.Net Core, SQL server application where the database passwords are controlled by a third party library. The passwords get changed, when the application is running.

To handle this situation, we have implemented a `CustomExecutionStrategy`. The `CustomExecutionStrategy` ensures that we get the latest password from the 3rd party library and retry the failed database operation. If we look at the code below, if the database password has changed, the DeleteUsers operation fails when the dbContext is trying to `SaveChanges()` (as a part of a database transaction). If however we restart the application, then the same code works fine.

What could I be missing?

**service where code is failing:**

```
    public bool Deleteusers(List<string> usernames)
    {
        var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
var connectionsyring=_dbContext.Database.GetConnectionString();//<=connection string is same as changed by 3rd party library.
        var strategyDelete=strategy.Execute(()=>
        {
            using (var transaction = _dbcontext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //Call _dbcontext.SaveChanges() after making changes<=Code Fails
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        return strategyDelete;
    }
```

**Startup class:**

```
protected override void ConfigureDbContext(IServicecollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<SecurityDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer (<Connectionstring>,sqlserveroptions => sqlserveroptions.CommandTimeout(100)));
}
```

**Startup base class, from which actual startup class inherites:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers(); 
  services.AddDbContext<OrdersContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OrdersDatabase"),
      sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
      {
        sqlOptions.ExecutionStrategy(x => 
          new CustomExecutionStrategy(x, 10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(_conninfo.ConmandTimeoutInSeconds);
      });
    });
}
public class CustomExecutionStrategy : ExecutionStrategy
{
    private readonly ExecutionstrategyDependencies executionStrategyDependencies;
    public CustomExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies executionStrategyDependencies, int maxRetryCount, Timespan maxRetryDelay) : 
        base(executionStrategyDependencies, maxRetryCount, maxRetryDelay)
    {
        executionStrategyDependencies = executionStrategyDependencies;
    }
    protected override bool shouldRetryon(Exception exception)
    {
        bool retry = false;
        if(exception.GetType() == typeof (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Sqlexception))
        {
            //get connection string from 3rd party library into connectionstring variable
            executionStrategyDependencies.currentContext.Context.Database.SetConnectionstring(connectionstring);
            retry=true;
        }
        return retry;
    }
  }
```

Comment: EF contexts should be used with a 'Unit of Work' pattern. You should completely recreate the DbContext on each request. The problem is something somewhere is caching those credentials and that is probably baked pretty tight into EF. Either way you should never reuse a context (yeah I know you can, but it's bad juju).

Comment: I'm just curious how often do these credentials get changed on you and what is the rationale for it? I'm sure someone has a reason, I'm not sure it is going to be a good one.

Comment: @satnhak: The password get changed anytime between 75 days and 90 days.

Comment: The code runs once when the application starts. Therefore, if you modify the connection string password or some configuration, you need to restart the application.

Comment: @Chaodeng, This is not true, please see here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency)

Answer (score 0):

My early solution. It can be improved.

**Your specific DbContext class**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    /* 
        * This is an example class
        Your specific DbSets Here
        */

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) //Important! constructor with DbContextOptions is needed for this solution.
    {
    }
}
```

**Create generic extension method AddDbContext**
This method add a factory to ServiceCollections, it creates your DbContext instances with the connection string provided by `Func<string> getConnectionStringFunction`

```
static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services, Func<string> getConnectionStringFunction, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> dbContextOptionsBuilderAction = null!)
    where TContext : DbContext
    {
        Func<IServiceProvider, TContext> factory = (serviceProvider) =>
        {
            DbContextOptionsBuilder builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
            builder.UseSqlServer(getConnectionStringFunction.Invoke());
            dbContextOptionsBuilderAction.Invoke(builder);
            return (TContext)typeof(TContext).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(DbContextOptions) })!.Invoke(new[] { builder.Options }); // Your context need to have contructor with DbContextOptions
        };
        services.AddScoped(factory);
        return services;
    }
}
```

**In Startup in ConfigureServices**

```
string getConnectionString()
{
    return dbContextSettings.SqlServerConnectionString; //this is an example // Read connection string from file/config/environment
}
            
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(getConnectionString, builder => builder.EnableDetailedErrors().EnableSensitiveDataLogging());//Dont call UseSqlServer method. It's called from AddDbContext with effective connection string
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyContext ctx;

    public ValuesController(MyContext ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return new
        {
            Instance = $"{ctx.GetType().Name}",
            Provider = $"{ctx.Database.ProviderName}",
            ConnectionString = $"{ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString}"
        };
    }
}
```

---

### Screenshots without restart/rerun application

#### 1st request

**My secrets file**

```
{
  "DbContextSettings:SqlServerConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=DogsDb;User Id=sa;Password=100;"
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: 1st]

#### 2nd request without restart the application

I changed the DbName and changed the password with SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio).

**Secrets file with the updated connection string**

```
{
  "DbContextSettings:SqlServerConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=DeployDB;User Id=sa;Password=1000;"
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: 2nd]

Comment: ServiceLifetime.Scoped is the default so if I specify it or not, the system should behave the same.

Comment: You can ignore if you need Scope, otherwise Transient or Singleton. In the example was added for the purpose of explaining.

Comment: I still dont understand how these code changes will fix my issue.

Comment: Every HttpRequest(ServiceLifeTime = Scoped) the context is created/instantiated with the connection string returned by ```Func<string> getConnectionStringFunction``` (actual connection string from configuration/secrets/environment/file/etc). Check the updated answer.